# How can i check if a changable value remains unchanged for a period of time (i.e. 7 min)

Tags: c#, sql

I have a column Status as a flag  (**P,W,S**)
The status (**P**) means this is still to be processed (pending)
if a record takes more than 7 minutes with status (P) that indicates something went wrong.
How to go around this?
Any help appreciated..

Comment: Going to have to give us more information: language, how you expect to find out, delay period in finding out, how rows are processed. And what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy solution :

Add a "StatusLastModified" DateTime column to the table and update that each time you set the value of Status.  (May want to write a trigger to handle that for you).

To find all values that haven't changed in the last 7 minutes, add that clause to your select statement.

Comment: Unless you've got historical revision records to compare changes, then `LastModified` could relate to any field in the table and you have no (entirely accurate) way of knowing which.

Comment: Added a clarification, but I meant for the datetime column to only get updated when the status changes.  The actual implementation is up to the OP (Stored Procedure / trigger / manual)

Answer (score 1):

When you set the record with flag "P", at that point, create a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in your code that runs for 7 mins. When the timer expires, handle the event and do a check to see if the record still has a flag of "P"

Note that the above method will require your application to be running for the duration, but you could add application logic to cater for this anyway.

Alternative you could add a TimeStamp in your database and set it when the flag is set to "P". The downside to this is that you will need to keep polling the data to see if the 7 minutes has passed or not so you can process the event in your application.

I guess you need to decide on your use case to determine how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

Use a timestamp alongside the data, something along the lines of `DateStatusChanged`, and update that field whenever the `Status` field is updated. Use this to check whether a user is in a state of `P` for longer than the predefined time.

This is a vague overview, in alignment with the substance of your query.